# Download image from server ajax uploaded from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, download, html2canvas

I currently user html2canvas to get a div as an image.

```
        html2canvas([document.getElementById("board")],{
            onrendered: function( canvas ) {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL();

                var request = $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"downloadPic.php",
                    data:{downloadPic : img}
                });
```

Then, I want to download that image (to the browser default download directory)

```
if(isset($_POST['downloadPic'])){

    $pic = $_POST['downloadPic'];
    $filteredData=substr($pic, strpos($pic, ",")+1); //html2canvas adds this
    $unencodeData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    $filename = "downloadedPic";

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($unencodeData));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($unencodeData);

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  If I do a file_put_contents("downloadedPic", $unencodedData) the picture is saved on my server successfully.

Do I need the header's config differently?

Comment: btw, you can download files in JS without sending them to the server, faster, safer, and works without internet connectivity...

Comment: How? I have been looking for it... whats the function?

Comment: http://danml.com/js/download.js, then use like download(atob(strDataURL.split(",")[1]), "image1.png", "image/png"); Works in FF, Ch, IE10...

Comment: well.. im sure exactly what its doing but it works. =)  ..now to look up blobbuilders